# Where is the location of my android sdk? I am using genymotion in ubuntu 16.10

Tags: android, genymotion, expo

While using expo they are telling me ->
" If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory."

[Like in the image "Use custom Android SDK tools". Now where should I point after clicking browse.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1rkG.png)

Comment: It will be like `/home/pc_userName/Android/Sdk` here. If you previously install Android SDK.

Comment: /home/pc_userName/after that there is no Android folder

Comment: Previously I installed android sdk through android studio.
But I may have accidentally deleted that particular folder.
Thank you for pointing that out. 

Your 
"It will be like /home/pc_userName/Android/Sdk here. If you previously install Android SDK."
Answers my question . Thank you Nitin .

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project Structure from the File menu. there you can see SDK directory.[image]

From here you can copy it and paste it into the Genymotion SDK option. May this help you.

Comment: I am in ubuntu and not using android studio.